# C - Sum of inputted numbers, until a number with 0 is inputted

Tags: c

So, I guess the way to decide if it ends with 0 is to divide it with 10, thus the modulo.. Here's the code.. I also tried with a while loop but it didn't work.. What am I doing wrong? Am I taking the right approach?

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(){
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    printf("Enter the numbers: ");

    for(int i=0; b % 10 != i; a++){
        scanf("%c", &b);
    }
    printf("You have entered %c numbers", a);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `b % 10 != i` does not seem to check if the last digit is 0.

Comment: @BillLynch `i` is always 0 in that code.

Comment: `"%c"` is for reading single characters. Use `"%d"` to read numbers. Likewise for the `printf`.

Comment: your for loop makes not too much sense

Comment: Sum of inputted numbers, or inputted digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrong scanf parameter.
2. Wrong logical expression.

```
int main(){
    int a = 0, b = 1;

    while(b%10)
    {
        scanf("%d", &b);
        a += !!(b%10);
    }
    printf("You have entered %d numbers", a);

return 0;
}
```